# maximization integral equation--Lagrangian?

Tags: integration, optimization

This is my first time posting. I'm not sure how to create the mathematical equation, so I've taken a screenshot of the paper I'm trying to understand. It's 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lMAi.png):

[image: Constrained optimization equation with integral]

I understand that it is a constrained optimization. My guess right now is maximize the function by adjusting a. The function we are maximizing is: $-exp(-r(s+ba-c(a))$, subject to the constraint after the integral sign.

Comment: We need more info. What is $c(a)$? Is that a function?

Comment: I don't see any constraints. The integral is just a constant and can be taken out of the max.

Comment: Thank you for such quick responses. Sorry that I am not sure how much to define. I have defined all variables here:.

This is the original paper: https://bit.ly/2MKARKz 

Yes, c(a) is a function. It is the "cost" of the person's action, depending on what the person chooses to exert--in terms of effort (a).
e is the natural constant 2.73.
r is a variable depicting risk tolerance.
s is an intercept variable depicting salary.
b is a bonus rate 
epsilon is  is a normally distributed noise term with zero mean and variance sigma^2.
phi(epsilon) is a normal density function.